# Compress iOS video using Phonegap

Tags: ios, video, cordova, compression, phonegap-plugins

Is there any tips, suggestions, or available plugins for Phonegap that might be available to Capture a video using Phonegap's capture feature, then programmatically compress or reduce the quality of the video such that it can be uploaded to a server?

The video file sizes can become rather large with videos longer than 5 minutes.  I would strongly prefer not to have save the video to the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible. You might have a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor), but up to Cordova 3.5 it is not possible to compress a video, and you can set its duration only on iOS